# Node3D Global_transform retunring nil

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have the following code for a Runway to launch fighters in my game.

```
extends Node3D
class_name Runway

@onready var end_node: Node3D = $End

var moving: bool = false

func set_moving(new_value: bool):
    moving = new_value

func get_end() -> Vector3:
    end_node.global_transform.origin

func get_start() -> Vector3:
    get_global_transform().origin

func is_free_to_land():
    true
```

How can I make the Node3D return it's global position? It has one but sometimes I get nil which is wird and not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `global_transform` of a `Node3D` cannot be nil.

You didn't post the error you got, but I suspect the error is that in this line:

```
end_node.global_transform.origin
```

Either `end_node` is null, or it is an invalid reference. Those aren't the same case...

---

For the first case (null), it means that this failed:

```
@onready var end_node: Node3D = $End
```

Which should have also given you an error. Which would stem from the node not actually being placed there.

Advice on this case would be to either use a unique name for the node, so you can use use `%` syntax with it. Or export a `Node` variable that you can set from the inspector.

---

For the second case (invalid reference), `end_node` was freed by other means beyond the script we are looking at.

If this is what you are facing then then you need to check:

```
if is_instace_valid(end_node)
    pass
```

If this is happening during a scene transition it is probably OK. However, if it is not, it might require further investigation into why it is happening.

*Try searching for `queue_free` in your code base. Barring that, consider connecting to the `tree_exiting` signal and checking `is_queued_for_deletion`. If that does not get it, be suspicious of `remove_child` + `free` combos. As last resort attach a script and check for `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE` in `_notification`.*

---

I would also expect `get_end` and `get_start` to be reporting errors because they do not return. *No, in GDScript the last statement does not automatically return, not even if it is the only statement.*

A little less evident, this is just a couple warnings (which might or might not be disabled in your settings):

```
func is_free_to_land():
    true
```

This does not return, but it does not state that it returns, so that is not an error. And also, `true` as an statement does nothing, which is not an error either.

---

And you probably can make `set_moving` into a setter.

Comment: Ah, I must have mixed in non explicit returns from rust. Alright, this is definetly the sign for me to use either Rust or C# with Godot. This language is missing too many convenience features for me to be happy with it. I love the editor over Bevy but not the scripting language. Thanks for the details though.